# Datatables laravel get json data with action buttons

Tags: php, laravel

I have a laravel function that i want to use to get json data that i want to display in a datatable. In the data i also have an action button edit and i want to pull the `$row->id` to create an edit button.

This is my code

```
public function getTasks()
    {
      $employees = Employees::select('*');
      return Datatables::of($users)
          ->addColumn('action', function ($e) {
              return '<a href="#edit-'.$e->id.'" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i> Edit</a>';
          })->make(true);
    }
```

I have the model `employees` already added but the json retruned has errors(thats what datatables says).

Where is the error in the code?. The client side code has no errors whatsoever.

Comment: can you also share your HTML section where you are embedding this response? can you also share your Debugger response code, See in Ajax response you are seeing the edit button code or not?

Comment: Oh its was a silly mistake. The table employees from sakila sample data in mysql has no id field, instead it has `emp_no`. I changed that and it has worked.